# Use of haven to read .sav (SPSS_ files): Change labelled vector to character string or factor

Tags: r, spss, r-haven

I am using the `haven` library to read an `.sav` (SPSS) file into R.

Some of the values are read as a `labelled` `vector`.

Here is an example of one:

```
> str(df$instructional_practice)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:4136] 2 2 6 6 8 8 NaN NaN 17 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "intructional practice teacher is using when signaled"
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:18] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:18] "1 Lecture" "2 Seatwk-Ind" "3 Review-Ind" "4 Seatwk-Grp" ...
```

How can I have the values for the `vector` be the label names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `haven::as_factor` to convert labelled vectors to factors, using the labels as the levels.

You can use this on individual vectors:

```
df$instructional_practice = as_factor(df$instructional_practice)
```

But you can also use it on the entire data.frame.  By default using `as_factor` on a data.frame will convert all labels to the factor levels for any labelled variable.

```
df = as_factor(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is very much like an R factor and I'm guessing (although it's kind of vague) you either want an R factor or you want a character vector. If you wanted an R character vector with values substituted for the current numeric values you could use the numeric values as an index into the names of the `labels` attribute:

```
 newvec <- names( attr( f$instructional_practice , "labels"))[f$instructional_practice]
```

Comment: this works (of course). I think the @aosmith may be preferable in some cases on the basis of being simple / part of `haven`.